How can I use BouncyCastle's Blowfish without requiring 8 bytes blocks?
In Delphi, both MyDAC and LockBox3 allow encrypting data with Blowfish without padding (resulting in a single character being encrypted to a single byte).
This data already exists, and I now need to be able to read/write it from C# with BouncyCastle but when trying to, I run into data length exceptions. What do I need to use for it to allow this kind of data ?
Reference of how I'm doing it with BouncyCastle :
var cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("Blowfish/CBC/NoPadding");
cipher.Init(true, new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(key), new byte[8]));
byte[] encryptedData = cipher.DoFinal(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DATA));

Creation of the key :
  PassBytes := BytesOf(@WideString(PASSWORD)[1], Length(PASSWORD) * SizeOf(WideChar));
  SetLength(keyBytes, 36);
  sha1 := THashSHA1.GetHashBytes(TBytesStream.Create(PassBytes));
  md5 := THashMD5.GetHashBytes(TBytesStream.Create(PassBytes));
  Move(sha1[0], keyBytes[0], 20);
  Move(md5[0], keyBytes[20], 16);

Reference of how I'm doing it with MyDAC :
table.Encryption.Encryptor := TMyEncryptor.Create(nil);
table.Encryption.Encryptor.DataHeader := ehNone;
table.Encryption.Encryptor.SetKey(keyBytes, 0, 32);
table.Encryption.Fields := 'Name';
// Insert a row with DATA in the Name

Reference of how I'm doing it with LockBox3 :
Codec := TCodec.Create(nil);
Codec.CryptoLibrary := TCryptographicLibrary.Create(nil);
Codec.StreamCipherId := BlockCipher_ProgId;
Codec.BlockCipherId := Blowfish_ProgId;
Codec.ChainModeId := CBC_ProgId;
  
setIV := TIVZero.Create(); // This sets the IV to all zeros
Codec.OnSetIV := setIV.SetIV;
  
SetLength(LBKeyBytes, 34);
Move(keyBytes[0], LBKeyBytes[1], 32);
LBKeyBytes[0] := 32; // Length of the key
LBKeyBytes[33] := 0; // Does the key contain the stores
Codec.InitFromStream(TBytesStream.Create(LBKeyBytes));
  
Codec.EncryptString(DATA, outputText, TEncoding.UTF8);

These implementations all give the same output when DATA = "ABCDEFGH", and both MyDAC and LockBox3 output are similar when encrypted just "A", but I can't get that to work with BouncyCastle. Are there other well-known encryption libraries for C# out there I could try ?
Edit to add : I did not choose to implement things like this. I'm just stuck having to deal with it.
Edit : Added the process to generate the key. For testing my key is "pass" and DATA will be "ABCD" etc according to which case I'm trying to make work.
I understand the MyDAC encryption seems non-standard, which is clearly where my problem is coming from :') Hopefully someone out there can figure out how to reproduce it using standard tooling.
MyDAC does not provide any documentation on their encryption, aside from saying it's Blowfish.

Blowfish is a block cipher. If a system allows you to use Blowfish as stream cipher this can not be plain Blowfish or Blowfish with CBC.

You're going to have to provide some links to documentation for these Delphi encryption methods because, as Robert indicated, what you're describing is impossible in standard CBC mode.

Can you post sample data for the Delphi side? Key, plaintext and ciphertext.

The sample data (password: pass, plaintext: ABCD) is incomplete, the ciphertext (and also keyBytes) is missing. That data would be helpful for those like me who do not have a Delphi environment.

I put the process to generate the key (which is sha1('pass') + md5('pass') truncated to 32) earlier in the question. But if you don't have a delphi env set up, it's going to be hard to answer such a specific delphi question ? In any case, encrypting 'AB' gives 0xE214, for example.

This post might be interesting. According to this, there seems to be a bug for plaintexts whose lengths are not an integer multiple of the block size (8 bytes for Blowfish).
